# Get URL parameters in React with AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I'm trying to set up an automated flow, where as part of that, I must recieve a code from an external API that is returned as a URL parameter, eg. `<my specified return url>/getcode/?code=xxxxxxx`. The way in which this code is returned is fixed outside of the return url.

At the moment, I am building my webapp using react and AWS Amplify, and so I first tried to use the `useSearchParams` method from react-router-dom, but I get told `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure.` upon testing this, with the stack trace pointing to `@aws-amplify/auth`.

I have done some research around this topic, and have come to the understanding that `useSearchParams` must have SSR enabled, which currently AWS Amplify does not support with React.

My question is, firstly, is my above diagnosis correct, and if so, does anyone know of any way to extract a URL parameter given that I can specify the return URL - perhaps directly pass it to a Lambda function? (what I was going to do after extracting it from the URL anyway)

Thanks

*example of how I am using react-router-dom:*

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom"


function GetCode() {
    const [queryParameters] = useSearchParams();

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Code: {queryParameters.get("code")}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default GetCode;
```

Edit:

Full stack trace:

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
The operation is insecure.
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js/AuthClass.prototype._handleAuthResponse/AuthClass</<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6271:30
step@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7340:17
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js/__generator/verb/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7289:14
rejected@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7255:24
```

and from the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure.    Auth.ts:2590
    node_modules bundle.js:6271
    step tslib.es6.js:100
    node_modules bundle.js:7289
    rejected tslib.es6.js:72
```

(included both as they are verbose in different ways)

Comment: As per [docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.15.0/hooks/use-search-params), `useSearchParams` for `react-router-dom` doesn't seem to need SSR in any way. Can you post your full stack trace please?

Comment: Agreed. This appears to be a purely AWS issue for whatever security rules it's trying to enforce. We need more details.

Comment: Thanks both, I have added the stack trace in the OP, I will continue to try and debug further and take a look into the linked docs.